# How to get, in WP page's script, a wp enqueued script (in Functions.php)?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-register-script, wp-localize-script

I’m very new to WP, and to JS as well, and need to do a simple change to existing code, so forgive my ignorance…

For getting the current User Id I followed examples and  added an action + function to functions.php of my child theme (pasted below)
Now I need to use it within a WP page within a `<script>…. </script>`

I tried to assign it into a var and failed (an example script part also pasted below, with non-functioning assignment).

**How do I do that right?**

```
Added to functions.php:

    add_action('init',’my demo_function');
    function my demo_function(){
        $theid=get_current_user_id();
        $params = array(
            'userid' => $theid
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'myuserscript', 'MyUserParams', $params );
        wp_enqueue_script('myuserscript');
    }
```

The example of code I tried in the WP page (which fails)

```
   <script>
    // when using this line I get the alert, as expected
    // var myData = "1234"; 
    // but when using this, alert is skipped, I suppose because this assignment is invalid 
    var myData = MyUserParams.userid; 
    alert("your id is: " + myData)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your script is registered with [**`wp_register_script`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) before your call to [**`wp_localize_script`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

So in your functions.php file:

```
add_action('init',’my demo_function');
function my demo_function() {


    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'myuserscript', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

    // Localize the script with your data
    $theid=get_current_user_id();
    $params = array(
        'userid' => $theid
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'myuserscript', 'MyUserParams', $params );

    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script('myuserscript');
}
```

Then the parameter would be available to you in the frontend

```
<script>
    var myData = MyUserParams.userid; 
    alert("your id is: " + myData)
</script>
```

**Reference:** [**wp_localize_script**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)